# Custom WordPress template shows blank page

Tags: wordpress

I have created my custom `Registration.php` page and set the template of my `test` page to it. My `Registration.php` code looks like this:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Registration */ ?>

<h1>Hello :)</h1>
```

When I go to `test` page it's just blank page. How can I fix this and show the content of Registration template in my test page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would need more information.  First thing that comes to mind is that the permissions aren't set for the new "Registration.php" file that you created.

Reference this post for correct WP permissions settings
https://www.getastra.com/blog/cms/wordpress-security/fixing-wordpress-file-permissions/

Good luck!

Comment: That seemed to be the problem. Thank you very much!